# Incorrect y-axes formatting when plotting multiple line plots using facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I have performed a latent class analysis using the poLCA package and require to plot the class fit criteria using facet_grid for ease of viaual comparison before selecting the 'best' model.

This was a 1-10 class LCA To perform the LCA i used example code taken from the following site (which helped me tremendously): https://statistics.ohlsen-web.de/latent-class-analysis-polca/

However, when I come to plot the fit criteria of my LCA, I am having issues with the formatting of y-axes in the separate plots. Instead of ggplot selecting an appropriate scale and providing the expected 'elbow plot' visual - it is plotting the y-axes specifically to the data points input from the dataframe and outputting straight line plots that have little visual value in determining 'best' model based on the criteria. When looking at the example elbow plots from the source website https://statistics.ohlsen-web.de/latent-class-analysis-polca/ they are very different to my own outputs...

I used the following code to produce the plots, also modified from the website source above:

```
fit.plot <- ggplot(results_young_lca) +
geom_point(aes(x = Model, y = Quality), size = 2) +
geom_line(aes(x = Model, y = Quality, group = 1)) +
theme_bw() +
labs(x = "", y = "", title = "Results for LCA in young adults (18 - 36 years)") +
facet_grid(Criteria ~ ., scales = "free") +
theme_bw(base_size = 8, base_family = "") +
theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "grey", size = 0.25),
legend.title = element_text(size = 8, face = "bold"),
axis.text = element.text(size = 8),
axis.title = element.text(size = 8),
legend.text = element.text(size = 10),
axis.line = element_line(color = "black"))
```

The output is as follows (apologies, this is taken from screenshot as data analysis platform doesnt allow transfer of anything in or out):

[image: Fit criteria for 1-10 class LCA. Issue with y-axes formatting]

I assume this to be some issue with the scales argument in facet grid, but I've tried multiple approaches to adapting this with no success. The alternative is to plot the criteria individually but this is extremely time consuming as I have a number of large LCAs across different groups to perform.

Any help much appreciated! Thanks

p.s first post so apologies if anything unclear and please let me know if I can clarify.

Comment: Your y-axis "Quality" seems to be being read in as a character rather than a numeric, the reading in of the data is the step you should focus on - we'd need that part of the code to answer the question.

Comment: What happens if you replace "Quality" with `as.numeric(Quality)`?

Comment: Thank you both for the rapid replies - @jared_mamrot replacing "Quality" with as.numeric(Quality) did the trick! 
Will return to the original code and fix at source so this issue doesnt happen again!

Comment: Glad you fixed your problem @L.Steell; thanks for providing all of the relevant info in your question :)